# How to bypass default_scope but still be able to use named scopes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

I have a User model where I have a default_scope to get all users which are still active. Along with the default scope, I also have named scopes. My User model looks something like:

default_scope { where(status: "active") }

scope :location,  -> (location) { where(location: location) }

For a specific query I need to bypass the default_scope and use location scope. I know I can use unscoped to bypass a scope but as per my understanding, unscope will bypass all the scopes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the default scope and then apply your custom scope, like this:

```rb
User.unscoped.location('London')
```

You do need to do it in this order, though, otherwise (as you say) the `unscoped` call will remove the scopes that were called before it.

Also, consider *not* using a default scope in this way. If you ever want (as in this example) to retrieve inactive users, you'll have problems. You're probably better having an `active` scope (and perhaps an `inactive` scope) that you can call when you want that limitation and *not* call when you don't! That way, your code will be much clearer about the records you expect to get back.

```rb
User.active.location('London')
User.inactive.location('London')
User.all.location('London')
etc.
```

Personally, I would only use a default scope for sorting records into date order so `first` and `last` return useful results (helpful when using uuids because, unlike integer ids, the records are in no particular order). But some people would disagree even with that!